# Why diode voltage is equal to source voltage when source voltage is less than 0.7?

Tags: diodes

In the constant voltage model
when the source voltage is less than 0.7, Why diode voltage is equal to source voltage not source voltage minus depletion region voltage?

Comment: You can't separate out the depletion region out from a diode.

Comment: The diode doesn't generate power

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a circuit.  However, I will assume a circuit consisting of a voltage source, the diode and a resistor in series.  If the voltage source is less than 0.7 volts, then the simple model of a diode would mean that the diode is off and no current is flowing. That means that the voltage across the resistor, in accordance with Ohm's law, is zero.  In that case the voltage across the diode is equal to the voltage source.